# Calling a function from inside another function?

Tags: matlab

I have 3 short functions that I've written inside 3 separate m files in Matlab.

The main function is called F_ and accepts one input argument and returns a vector with 3 elements.

Element 1 and 2 of the output from F_ are (supposed to be) calculated using the functions in the other 2 m files, lets call them theta0_ and theta1_ for now.

Here's the code:

```
function Output = F_(t)

global RhoRF SigmaRF

Output = zeros(3,1);

Output(1) = theta0(t);
Output(2) = theta1(t) - RhoRF(2,3)*sqrt(SigmaRF(2,2))*sqrt(SigmaRF(3,3));
Output(3) = -0.5*SigmaRF(3,3);

end
```

and

```
function Output = theta0_(t)

global df0dt a0 f0 SigmaRF

Output = df0dt(t) + a0 + f0(t) + SigmaRF(1,1)/(2*a0)*(1-exp(-2*a0*t));

end
```

and

```
function Output = theta1_(t)

global df1dt a1 f1 SigmaRF

Output = df1dt(t) + a1 + f1(t) + SigmaRF(2,2)/(2*a1)*(1-exp(-2*a1*t));

end
```

I've created handles to these functions as follows:

```
F = @F_;
theta0 = @theta0_;
theta1 = @theta1_;
```

When I run F_ via it's handle with any value of `t` I get the following error:

```
F_(1)
Undefined function 'theta0' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in F_ (line 9)
Output(1) = theta0(t);
```

Please assist. What am I doing wrong here?

I only want to be able to call one function from within another.

Comment: You defined it as `theta0_` and call it as `theta0`. Also, you don't need to call it through handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each function has its own workspace, and since you didn't create `theta0` inside the workspace of function `F_` you get an error.

Chances are that you don't need that extra level of indirection and you can use `theta0_` in your function.

If you do need that extra level of indirection, you have several options:

- Pass the function handle as an argument:

  ```
  function Output = F_ ( t, theta0, theta1 )
      % insert your original code here
  end
  ```
- Make `F_` a nested function:

  ```
  function myscript(x)

  % There must be some reason not to call theta0_ directly:
  if ( x == 1 )
      theta0=@theta0_;
      theta1=@theta1_;
  else
      theta0=@otherfunction_;
      theta1=@otherfunction_;
  end

      function Output = F_(t)
          Output(1) = theta0(t);
          Output(2) = theta1(t);
      end % function F_

  end % function myscript
  ```
- Make the function handles global. You must do that both in `F_` and where you set `theta0` and `theta1`. And make sure that you don't use global variables with the same name somewhere else in your programm for something different.

  ```
  % in the calling function:
  global theta0
  global theta1

  % Clear what is left from the last program run, just to be extra safe:
  theta0=[]; theta1=[];

  % There must be some reason not to call theta0_ directly.
  if ( x == 1 )
      theta0=@theta0_;
      theta1=@theta1_;
  else
      theta0=@otherfunction_;
  end

  F_(1);

  % in F_.m:
  function Output = F_(t)
      global theta0
      global theta1
      Output(1)=theta0(t);
  end
  ```
- use `evalin('caller', 'theta0')` from inside `F_`.
  That might lead to problems if you call `F_` from somewhere else, where `theta0` is not declared or even used for something different.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the detailed reply. Few questions, what do you mean by indirection? Do you mean that I can call the functions from `F_` using their function names (`theta0_` and `theta1_`) and not have to use function handles (`theta0` and `theta1`)? Maybe I just don't get global variables, but for my work now, there are variables in the base workspace that I want these functions to use without having to pass them into the function e.g. `df0dt a0 f0 SigmaRF`. Is the way I've done in in my theta functions correct?

Comment: The global declarations look good, but you also have to declare them as global in your base workspace. Or you could use `df0dt=evalin('base','df0dt');` in your functions to access the base workspace. By indirection I mean the direct way to call `theta0_` is to type in `theta0_`. If you don't know beforehand what function you have to call, you can add a level of indirection: You declare a function handle and set it to the correct function, and at the call site you call the function the handle points to. This is what you have done with `theta0` which refers to `theta0_` but can be changed.